# Wordpress Widget Hero Image Covers Drop Down Menu

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, siteorigin

I am finializing work with the wordpress site. I am using Colorib Shapely template and I facing problem with dropdown menu that is behind the Siteorigin Hero Image widget. I can't figure out on which div shall I put z-depth property in order to make it work.

url: www.a-dent.net
Top Menu -> USLUGI

Can sb help with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give

```
  z-index: 999;
```

to your

```
  li.dropdown
```

And you are good to go.

Comment: Great. Thank you.